# Can't debug GOT table lazy resolution; entry already resolved before the first call

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, dynamic-linking, got

I have a small program using a dynamic library and I want to follow the GOT resolution. I reach the following lines when calling `_print_string`. Now, The first line should be first set to the next one `push $0x0` to solve the actual address of `_print_string`. But when executing line by line, the correct address for `_print_string` is already stored in the GOT. I ran gdb, put a breakpoint at `_print_string@plt` and executed the run command. The library I'm using is a shared one (not static).

```
0x0000555555555030  ? jmp    *0x2f8a(%rip)        # 0x555555557fc0 <_print_string@got.plt>
0x0000555555555036  ? push   $0x0
0x000055555555503b  ? jmp    0x555555555020
```

EDIT:

Here is the initial code for the main function (my program is written in at&t assembly x86-64 architecture). I only pasted the code until the function call.

```
.global main
.type main function

main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    push %rdi # argc (%rbp - 8)
    push %rsi # argv (%rbp - 16)
    push $0   # index (i) (%rbp - 24)
    leaq nargsmsg(%rip), %rdi
    call _print_string
```

EDIT2:

A small example where I the GOT entry for puts is already solved

```
.global main
.type main function

.text

main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    leaq string(%rip), %rdi
    call puts
    mov $0, %rax
    leave
    ret

.data
string: .asciz "Hello world\n"
```

EDIT3:

1. I'm using [gdb-dashboard](https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard), but disabling it didn't affect the
   issue.
2. I tried compiling with `-z norelro` and checking whether `LD_BIND_NOW` was defined. `LD_BIND_NOW` was not defined, and `-z norelro` didn't have any effect (I checked that the option took effect by using `checksec`).

Comment: Does anything take the address of `_print_string` instead of just calling it?  If so, it might promote the GOT entry to early binding (during dynamic linking) instead of lazy.  (Similarly, `gcc -fno-plt` code-gen uses the GOT entry directly without the PLT, and would force early binding if there are any calls to it like `call *_print_string@gotpcrel(%rip)`.)  Also, why is there a leading `_`?  Linux ELF doesn't decorate C names with a leading underscore.

Comment: Dear Peter,

I edited my question with all the code before the `_print_string` call. The function name uses a leading `_` because I written all myself in assembly and at the time I wrote it I thought that functions in assembly should be decorated with a leading underscore, and I never went back to modify the name. My compilation only uses the `-z noexecstack` flag, there is no `-fno-plt` flag.

Comment: Works for me with `call puts`; single-step into its PLT entry does get me into code from `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, on my Arch Linux system.  I assembled+linked with `gcc foo.S`, on a file with a `main:` that does `push %rbp` / `lea` / `call puts` / ...

Comment: I updated with another example that only calls `puts`, the program works as expected but when I debug it with gdb the GOT entry for `puts` is already solved/filled.

I'm using `gdb-dashboard` (https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard) to make gdb more user friendly, maybe that is doing something that causes the resolution of all addresses in the GOT?

Comment: IDK, maybe, although that seems unlikely and intrusive.  I'm using plain-vanilla GDB with `layout reg`.   Can you use `starti` (to break before the first user-space instruction) and set a watchpoint on the GOT entry to see what writes it before the start of `main`?  Perhaps you have some LD-related environment variables??  Or perhaps there's a way to configure the dynamic-linker to always early-bind, and your distro does that?

Comment: Update: I tried disabling gdb-dashboard, and the behaviour is the same. I also tried using `-z norelro` when compiling the last example and still have the same behaviour.

Comment: If I use `starti` the code I see is too far from what I can understand. I tried `starti` followed by a `break puts@plt` and `continue`, and the GOT entry was already resolved.

Comment: That confirms nothing actually calls `puts` via the PLT before `main`, but we already knew that since no extra newlines got printed.  But perhaps something else invoked the resolver for it.  You should be able to find the address of the GOT entry while stopped at `starti`, e.g. from disassembling `puts@plt` and looking at the absolute address. (e.g. `b puts@plt` shows me the code address, then `disas 0x555555555030` shows me `0x555555558000 <puts@got.plt>`.   Then like I said before, set a watch point like `watch -l *(void**)0x555555558000` to break when anything changes the GOT entry.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that address resolution for dynamic libraries was being done when loading the executable (instead of using lazy linking).

To avoid it, I added these flags when compiling my executable: `-z lazy -z norelro`